# Private NuGet compatibility between different frameworks

Tags: .net-core, .net-framework-version, nuget-server

We have several projects that we use in most all of our projects.  We are wanting to move them to a private NuGet store.  We have installed NuGet.Server and have it working with our .net framework versions of the projects.  We also have most of these common projects that we need to use in .net core projects, so our team has created core versions.  When I try to publish the core version of the package to the NuGet, it does not really differentiate between the core and .net FW versions, that is when we try to consume the packages from the store on a project that is based on core, it show both versions of the package, instead of just the version for core.  Is this something that we deployed incorrectly or are there other issues that we don't know?
Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed the majority of the issues we had, including loading of symbols, using BaGet version of nuget server. It is available on Github